# Как найти числа между пробелами без самих пробелов?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Как найти все числа от 5 до 10 знаков включительно, которые находятся между пробелами или концом/началом строки? Нужно найти именно числа, без пробелов.

Например:

`181523539532037 52844 072 301` - должно найти только `52844`

`BIC 55555 77777 9999999 554664` - должно найти `55555` `77777` `9999999` `554664`

`123456` - если в строке нет ничего, кроме `123456`, то найти должно `123456`

Я не силён в регулярных выражениях, попробовал `\D\d{5,10}\D`, но, во-первых, оно включает сами пробелы, во-вторых, если между двумя числами только один пробел - не находит второе число.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используйте следующее выражение в методе `re.findall`:

```
r'(?<!\S)[0-9]{5,10}(?!\S)'
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/qDTm1D/2).

**Подробности**

- `(?<!\S)` - сразу перед пятью-десятью цифрами должен быть пробельный символ или начало строки
- `[0-9]{5,10}` - пять-десять цифр
- `(?!\S)` - сразу после пяти-десяти цифр должен быть пробельный символ или конец строки.

Код на Python:

```
import re
texts = ['181523539532037 52844 072 301', 'BIC 55555 77777 9999999 554664', '123456']
for text in texts:
    print('Ищем в {}'.format(text))
    print(re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[0-9]{5,10}(?!\S)', text))
```

Вывод:

> ```
> Ищем в 181523539532037 52844 072 301
> ['52844']
> Ищем в BIC 55555 77777 9999999 554664
> ['55555', '77777', '9999999', '554664']
> Ищем в 123456
> ['123456']
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
n [5]: re.findall(r'\b\d{5,10}\b', '181523539532037 52844 072 301')
ut[5]: ['52844']

n [6]: re.findall(r'\b\d{5,10}\b', 'BIC 55555 77777 9999999 554664')
ut[6]: ['55555', '77777', '9999999', '554664']

n [7]: re.findall(r'\b\d{5,10}\b', '123456')
ut[7]: ['123456']
```

Comment: `\b` найдёт совпадения не только между пробелов.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, что-то мне подсказывает, что автору нужен вариант находящий числа в начале/конце предложения и т.д....

Comment: Какое у вас вольное толкование вопроса однако :) *все числа от 5 до 10 знаков включительно, которые находятся между пробелами или концом/началом строки*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, это интерпретация попытки автора вопроса `\D\d{5,10}\D` ...